# How to handle null or Non required column in json in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

[image]

sample api url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

[image]

title is not a mandatory field in received json. It may or may not be part of each record.

When this field is missing in record, @{items('For_each')['title']} this throws an exception.

I want the value of myVariable to set as 'N/A' in that case. How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make the assumption that this is an array and that you have a set schema in the HTTP trigger. If the schema is set, make sure you remove `Title` as a required field.
[image: Required HTTP fields]

Using these asumptions you should be able to do the following with `Coalesce()`

If `Title` now is not present in the body of the HTTP request the `Title` will be equal to 'N/A'

[image: Logic App]

Using postman to test, note, the result is backward as it is the first object sent in my array.
[image: Postman]

Answer (score 1):

Cause you url data all have the title, so I test with `When a HTTP request is recived` trigger to get the json data.

In this situation the data could only be like this:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,

    "body": "xxxxx"
  }
```

not like the below one:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title":,
    "body": "xxxxxxxxx"
  }
```

I test with the first one, it did show the error message: property 'title' doesn't exist,. So here is my solution, after the action `Set variable`, add an action to set the variable you want and set the action run after `Set variable` has failed like the below picture.

[image]

[image]

After configuration, if the title doesn't exist, it will be set as `N/A` as you want.

[image]

Hope this could help you, if this is not what you want or you have other questions, please let me know.